# Create a SharePoint abstract parent content type

Tags: inheritance, sharepoint-2010, content-type, abstract

Is it possible to make a content type "abstract" in SharePoint 2010, i.e. users will only able to use the content types that inherit from the parent, and not create items/lists that use the base content type directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a certain extent, declaring the content type as hidden may help you. More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.hidden.aspx

Comment: Nice! "You can use this property to specify that a content type be hidden. Hidden content types are not displayed on the New menu for list views. Therefore, users cannot create new items of that content type from the list."